# Parsing XML, how is this actually done?

Tags: ruby, xml, lexical-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Roll your own XML parser / XML parsing algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917430/roll-your-own-xml-parser-xml-parsing-algorithm)

Once upon a time when I first started to program I tried to write an XML parser using regexp. This failed miserably.

Ever since then, I have used libraries to do all the work for me, however I would like to give parsing another shot. I only want to read RSS feeds, so it probably does not need to support the entire spec.

All I can find on the internet on the subject are:
1) Instructions to not do this 
2) Samples/Tutorials showing how to use a certain library
3) Folks saying its impossible.

The thing is there are numerous libraries that read in XML in each language, Nokogiri for Ruby/written in C; `javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser` for Java, etc...

So.. how are they doing it? I'm pretty indifferent to whether I use pull/sax/dom.

Comment: In many cases you can read the source for yourself - why don't you pick a library and look at the code? I would strongly advise *against* doing it yourself though... it'll be a *lot* of work, and the chances of you ending up with as reliable a result as a well-tested library are very slim.

Comment: The libraries all seem quite dense to me as most are written in Java C++ and C, of which I only have perfunctory knowledge. I was hoping for more of a general process, which I could look up on my own. I don't really need to build a reliable result, this is more of a 'write some code to see how this works' type deal.

Comment: "I only want to read RSS feeds, so it probably does not need to support the entire spec." <-- *cough*. This is why one uses an *existing* library that is *well tested and conforms to the applicable specifications* :) And yes, regular expressions (used exclusively) will fail because they can cannot describe XML. Regular expressions as part of the [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) (transforms text into tokens) though, are very valuable. After the token stream is created it can be turned into a DOM (validation at start) or exposed as stream (validation during iteration).

Comment: @pst, you are assuming I need this to actually work and accomplish something. I just want to learn how these things work. The best way to learn is usually by doing.

Comment: @providence Start with the link on lexers :) It might be beneficial to move on to looking at more general-purpose grammar parsing constructs after that such as LL/recursive-descent (if building a DOM), although XML is very simple in this regard. Turning the text into tokens is the first big step. For a stream-based parser the stream "handler" is just called at the appropriate time and the structure is verified on-the-fly. Without XSD/DTD support, etc, this means checking for matched closing tags.

Comment: Thanks, a guide like this is exactly what I was looking for. If you turn it into an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: The XML parser that ruby uses (REXML) is actually written in Ruby. You can look at the [source code on Github](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/trunk/lib/rexml).